# How to parse this JSON in PHP

Tags: json

I build this JSON from my form generated on my website. 
I now want to push the individual item's to the database, so I need to be able to pull out instruction by iteration.

$instruction0
$instruction1

and the ingredients which sit inside an instruction.

When trying to parse the JSON I get an error, I am not sure how to read it in PHP. (AKA PHP NOOB) I am able to get all my item's needed via Python without any issues.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gomfq.png)

```
[
  [
    {
      "instruction": "Enter text here...asdada"
    },
    {
      "ingredient": "Beetroot",
      "amount": "2",
      "type": "grams"
    },
    {
      "ingredient": "Beetroot",
      "amount": "1",
      "type": "grams"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "instruction": "Enter text here..sdfsdf."
    },
    {
      "ingredient": "Carrot",
      "amount": "2",
      "type": "grams"
    },
    {
      "ingredient": "Beetroot",
      "amount": "525",
      "type": "grams"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Screenshots are very unhelpful. Please paste in the actual code you're writing, and the error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** with a second parameter 'true' to specify you want your output as an associative array.

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

Secondly, if you are posting this json string manually into your code, you need to wrap it inside quotes, so based on that

```
$json = '[ [ { "instruction": "Enter text here...asdada" }, { "ingredient": "Beetroot", "amount": "2", "type": "grams" }, { "ingredient": "Beetroot", "amount": "1", "type": "grams" } ], [ { "instruction": "Enter text here..sdfsdf." }, { "ingredient": "Carrot", "amount": "2", "type": "grams" }, { "ingredient": "Beetroot", "amount": "525", "type": "grams" } ] ] ';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can iterate through `$array` as normal